# How to merge two pandas dataframes with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes like the following:

```
df1
      A       B 
0     0       3
1     0       2
2     1       5
3     1       3
4     2       5
5   'Ciao'  'log'
6     3       4


df2
      A   B 
0     0   -1
1     0   20
2     1   -2
3     1   33
4     2   17
```

I want to merge the two dataframes in order that the if `A==0` keep the values of `df1` and otherwise keep the values of `df2`.

At the end, I would like something like the follwing

```
df2
      A   B 
0     0   3
1     0   2
2     1   -2
3     1   33
4     2   17
```

Comment: Are the DataFrames aligned? Is the duplicated index 3 in df1 a typo?

Comment: The question is somewhat underspecified.  "If `A==0`"... in df1?  In df2?  Both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the dataframes are aligned (and that the duplicated index 3 in `df1` is a typo), you do not want a `merge` but rather a conditional using [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
out = df1.where(df1['A'].eq(0), df2)
```

Output:

```
   A   B
0  0   3
1  0   2
2  1  -2
3  1  33
4  2  17
```

*NB. if you really want a merge, you have to further explain the logic of the merge and provide a non-trivial example.*

Updated example:

You seem to still have partially aligned indices, but want to get the intersection:

```
out = (df1.where(df1['A'].eq(0), df2)
          .loc[df1.index.intersection(df2.index)]
      )
```

Or:

```
out = (df1.reindex_like(df2)
          .where(df1['A'].eq(0), df2)
      )
```

output:

```
     A     B
0  0.0  -1.0
1  0.0  20.0
2  1.0  -2.0
3  1.0  33.0
4  2.0  17.0
```

Comment: yes it was a typo. Please see the revised version with a nontrivial example

Comment: @emax the example is still ambiguous, can the 0/0/1/1/2 be in a different order? Is the `0` position used to affect the value?

Comment: I want to copy the value of `df1` in `df2` only for `A==0`

Comment: Let me rephrase, is my updated solution working for you? If not, why?